# Why AVFormatContext pointer is initialized in a non-global struct object, while NULL in a global object?

Tags: c++, struct, ffmpeg, global

The code is almost similar to filtering _video.c, one example code in ffmpeg doc.

In the original example file, there are many global static variables. Here is one snippet of the 1st version code (same as the original sample):

```
static AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx;
static AVCodecContext *dec_ctx;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

// ....  other code
    if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&fmt_ctx, filename, NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot open input file\n");
        return ret;
    }

// .... other code

}
```

Since all these variables serve for open a video file, I prefer to group them. So the purpose of my code is to rearrange these variables, making the source file more structed.

The first idea came to my mind is to use struct.

```
struct structForInVFile {
    AVFormatContext *inFormatContext;
    AVCodecContext *inCodecContext;
    AVCodec* inCodec;
    AVPacket inPacket;
    AVFrame *inFrame;
    int video_stream_index;
    int inFrameRate;
    int in_got_frame;
};
```

Now the 2nd version of code becomes:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

// .... other code
structForInVFile inStruct;

    if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&inStruct.inFormatContext, filename, NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot open input file\n");
        return ret;
    }

// .... other code

}
```

Result for the 2nd version: the code can not work at the  avformat_open_input. No error information. The program silently exits. 
Through debugging, I find that: inStruct.inFormatContext:  0xffffefbd22b60000

In the 3rd version of code, I set inStruct as a global variable.
The code becomes:

```
structForInVFile inStruct;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

// .... other code
    if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&inStruct.inFormatContext, filename, NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot open input file\n");
        return ret;
    }

// .... other code

}
```

Result for the 3rd version: the code works.
Through debugging, I find that: inStruct.inFormatContext:  0x0

So I think the reason is that: the AVFormatContext should be zero-initialized for  avformat_open_input to work.
Now, the question is:

Why AVFormatContext pointer is initialized in a non-global struct object, while zero-initialized in a global object?

I do not know any difference of definition of a struct object as a global variable or a non-global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy. According to the **C++ Standard** in **3.6.2 Initialization of non-local objects**:

*Objects with static storage duration (3.7.1) shall be zero-initialized (8.5) before any other initialization takes place.*

**NOTE**: Your question is duplicate. Please search StackOverflow more carefully before asking.

Comment: Thank you. I searched, and looked into the C++ prime. But I think I did not find good keywords to search the right pages.